# Facebook page tab triggers IE "Only secure content is displayed" message

Tags: html, facebook, internet-explorer, ssl, facebook-page

I've added a tab to my facebook page using Static Html: iframes tab app. 
Works fine in chrome but in IE I get "Only secure content is displayed" notification.
The background image is linked with SSL and there is no other outer content linked to the page, only html with text so I have no idea about the cause...
Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style type="text/css">
  body {
    direction: rtl;
    background-image: url('https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-8GcYUqtmItc/UDc8OSEOdZI/AAAAAAAAD_g/denZSy7Be_0/s800/bg.jpg');
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    font: Arial;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #00000;
  }
  #header {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 190px;
  }
</style>
<title>Page Title</title>

</head>
<body>
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="content">
<table width="90%"  cellpadding="10" border="0" align="center">
        <tr>
          <td align="right" dir="rtl">
            <p>
                Some text...
            </p>
          </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div><!-- content -->
</body></html>
```

Here is the actual page link: http://facebook.com/#!/GioraSalz/app_349708898445501

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In facebook tab apps, the secure content is everything on https://facebook.com. Since your site is probably not secured with SSL, IE will not show it because somewhere deep in the bowels of IE settings is a "only show secure content." if you want to remove this, just get a ssl certificate. they're pretty cheap

Comment: That's the point, there is no "your site".
It's a tab added to my facebook fan page using Static HTML: iframes tab app.
There are no links to outer content except the background image, which is on Picasa web albums and is linked using SSL.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Hrm. Did you check your IE settings? How does it work with other browsers?

Comment: It works great on Chrome, it's IE that makes all the trouble.
IE settings are normal.
I've also tried it from several machines running IE, same problem.
Thing is, I want the page to be compatible for any user running IE so changing settings doesn't help much.

Comment: Right. Well. What version of IE is it? If it's like a modern one. I can't really help you. I'm a mac. But, there are MSDN forums which are good

Comment: It's IE 9. Thanks for the efforts.

Comment: Tell us the actual page tab URL please, so we can have a look at it “live”.

Comment: Using Firebug (why didn’t you do that yourself?) it becomes immediately visible that there’s a request for `http://gioracampaign.freeiz.com/guidelines/images/bg.jpg` – that’s a non-secure URL, and therefor triggers the warning. (It’s hard-coded in the first `<style>` block in the head of your document. Replace `http://gioracampaign.freeiz.com/…` with `//gioracampaign.freeiz.com/…`)

Comment: It's not it. If you look in the above code, I've already tried a secure URL.
I've changed it back, so you can have a look now that it's secure URL.
Thanks.